# how to do a ranking of moving average in DAX

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

Assume there's a table T1 with columns [state],[product],[price],[store],[date], and a time  table T2. There's a relationship between T2's [pk_date] column and T1's [date] columnit.

and I create a measure [5days moving average price]:

calculate
 (
   average('T1'[price])
,
 DATESINPERIOD 
(
        'T2'[pk_Date],
        LASTDATE ( 'T2'[pk_Date] )-1,
        -5,
        DAY
    )
)

but for certain state and product, is there anyway I can get a rank of stores based on the [5days moving average price]? I tried something like 
:=RANKX(ALLSELECTED('T1'[store]),[5Days Moving  AVERAGE PRICE],,1)
but it didn't work.

Comment: The closest one I can get is :=RANKX(ALLSELECTED('T1'),[5Days Moving AVERAGE PRICE],,1) , it kind of works, but when the [5Days Moving AVERAGE PRICE] has very close value, and 10.1 and 10.11, this rankx will  give them both the same rank, like rank=3 for 10.1, rank=3 for 1.11 too. I've stuck here cluelessly

Comment: How about `:=RANKX(ALLSELECTED('T1'),([5Days Moving AVERAGE PRICE]*100),,1)`?